# What's a list of theological terms to describe how one approaches the bible?

Tags: exegesis

I know people who believe the bible is true and authoritative, and insist you get best meaning from King James Version. At the same time, I've heard a pastor quoted as saying, "You can trust the bible, just not the one you've got," implying it was true and authoritative, just not necessarily in the English versions we carry around.  Further still I've met theological-liberals who say things like "Bible contains the Word of God." I'm not interested in debating the merits of any approach.

What are the terms used to describe the main schools of thought? I'm particularly interested in the flavors of "literalism", if there are any objectively-describable differences in camps here.

Comment: First clue this is a list question: It's asking for a list :)

Comment: You mean, for example, the "Dispensational Camp," with adherents such as Cyrus I. Scofield and Charles Caldwell Ryrie? There's a good introduction to D'ism at http://www.theologicalstudies.org/resource-library/dispensationalism/421-what-is-dispensationalism

Comment: No, not eschatology. Differing schools of thought on how to be literal. And just extended definitions; no assessment if best ones, if possible, thanks.

Comment: I'm hoping this stays open, and you get a good answer but if not, here's one method that is considered to be "correct" by most conservative/literalist views: https://bible.org/seriespage/contextual-method-biblical-interpretation  which also covered here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/from-a-fundamentalist-viewpoint-what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-bible-literally

Comment: A distinctive eschatology is but one element of Dispensationalism.  One basis (perhaps THE basis) of Dispensationalism is the belief in the "verbal, plenary inspiration" of the Bible as the Word of God, which of course includes both literal and figurative elements (e.g., metaphor, symbolism, rhetorical figures and tropes, genealogies, historical narrative, parables, and much more).  Here's an interesting website from a primarily RC perspective that summarizes different methods of interpretation, including "literalist" methods:  http://www.bible-researcher.com/catholic-interpretation.html

Comment: @rhetorician, your link is exactly what I'm looking for.  Ultimately, I am trying to understand differences between Jerry Falwell's "Bible-believing" or Fundamentalist approach, and the methods some extremely theologically conservative Lutherans, who have explicitly gone through denominational splits over interpretation methods.

Comment: The Lutheran thing is something I'm interested in, too. Maybe I'll google a few key words to see what I come up with. Don  I just googled and came across an interesting article by the Missouri Synod at http://www.lcms.org/Document.fdoc%3Fsrc%3Dlcm%26id%3D305 It's from 1973, so it's certainly not up to date, but it's probably worth a read.

Comment: @rhetorician, why don't you Answer this and I may start a new Question with my refined interest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to interpret the Bible literally?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/what-does-it-mean-to-interpret-the-bible-literally)

Comment: @pterandon: I would suggest, then, asking questions about Jerry Fallwell, or Fundamentalists, rather than asking for vague lists, which are off-topic/non-constructive.

Comment: @Flimzy:  You may be right about "vague lists," but I wouldn't be surprised if in studying the "literal approach to biblical interpretation" down through the ages, we just might discover there to be "gold in them thar hills."  Even starting with the contrasts between the Origin of Alexandria "school of interpretation" and the Theophilus of Antioch "school of interpretation" in the second and third centuries A.D., there just may be nuggets of wisdom to be found by first, understanding each camp, and second, by avoiding the extremes of either and/or both "camps."  I'm just saying . . ..

Comment: @rhetorician: I never said there wasn't wisdom in literal Bible interpretation. I said this question isn't fit for SE.

Comment: @Flimzy: Sorry, I forgot I wasn't in Biblical Hermeneutics beta but, rather, SE Christianity!  As the young people say nowadays, "My bad."  I'll leave a comment for pterandon, suggesting he "migrate" the question over to biblical hermeneutics, though I'm not exactly sure how to migrate a question.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @pterandon:  I suggest you ask this question on Biblical Hermenutics Beta, a sister site, of sorts, to SE Christianity.  ALTHOUGH (and I just thought of this), by rewording your question by including the phrase (e.g.) "literal biblical and Christian interpretation down through the centuries, from Theophilus of Antioch to Ravi Zacharias"!  Phrased in that way, the question is more oriented toward Christianity.

Comment: @rhetorician: List questions aren't on topic on BH, either.

Comment: Also, the subject of this question is probably a better fit here than on BH, since it's about Biblical *interpretation*.

Comment: @Flimzy:  Unless I'm mistaken, hermeneutics is the science and art of biblical interpretation, is it not?  Besides, I have a feeling the OP is not asking for a simple list, per se, but terms for the different schools of thought within the literalist camp and, I assume, what differentiates the different schools.  Maybe I'm reading too much into the OP's question, but IMO that's what he's asking, and he deserves an answer in either forum, though biblical hermeneutics might be a better fit.

Comment: @pterandon:  Check out "A History of Biblical Interpretation" by Alan J. Hauser & Duane F. Watson, the first volume of a projected multivolume set. Volume 1 takes us from inner-exegesis in the Tanakh up to the interpretation of the NT apocrypha.  Future volumes will include the medieval and Reformation periods, the eighteenth and nineteenth centuries, which saw the rise of modern biblical criticism, and the twentieth century. For a free sample, go to http://www.questia.com/read/119907701/a-history-of-biblical-interpretation

Comment: @pterandon:  Also check out "The Bible in the Churches: How Various Christians Interpret the Scriptures" by Kenneth Hagen, with the chapter "EVANGELICAL INTERPRETATION OF SCRIPTURE: The Background to Contemporary Evangelical Exposition," by GRANT R. OSBORNE
Again, go to http://www.questia.com/library/7410918/the-bible-in-the-churches-how-various-christians

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, and worth a measured response, either here or in Stack Exchange Biblical Hermeneutics Beta.  By the way, I assume you are not after a mere list of different schools of thought vis a vis literalism but an explanation of what distinguishes one "faction" of literalists from another faction of literalists.

According to Dr. Bob Thiel, Theophilus of Antioch, who wrote c. 180 A.D., was one of the earliest proponents of the "literal" approach to biblical interpretation. Thiel, by the way, is known online as COGwriter.com, and he is a widely published spokesperson for the Continuing Church of God (with which I am in no way affiliated).  Thiel contrasts Theophilus's approach with the "allegorical" approach to biblical interpretation espoused by Origin of Alexandria, who borrowed extensively from  Clement of Alexandria.  These two "schools of thought" or "camps" are in some ways the antithesis of each other.

On the one hand, Theophilus, a literalist, would explain the concept of God's anger in very human terms, albeit not in a sinful sense.  Call it righteous indignation or an aspect of the wrath of God, but God's anger is literal, according to Theophilus, and its expression is real.

On the other hand, Origin, an allegorist, would insist the human concept of anger is not worthy of God but must be explained not in anthropomorphic terms but in figurative and allegorical terms.  In other words, there needs to be a "deeper" meaning than simple, human anger.  The literalist camp would insist that while there may in fact be an occasional deeper meaning in a biblical text, the "default setting" (my term, copyright 2013!) for reading the Bible should be literal, not figurative.

Since the third century in the Common Era, variations of the two camps (not to mention other, competing camps) have come and gone.  I would not be surprised if by google-ing various key terms in this regard, one might come up with a scholarly work which traces the evolution--or devolution, as the case may be--of the literal method.  In fact, I will do that search myself and edit this answer if I find any sources worth quoting.

Additionally, I would not be surprised, either, if someone has written a tome on the various ways in which Christian literalists have gone about the art of interpretation since the first century A.D.  Come to think of it, the "higher critics," so called, may in fact be literalists in some ways.  What sets them apart from other literalists, however, is their tendency to explain away or discount such things as miracles and even the inspiration of the Scripture by the Holy Spirit.  In other words, they may believe there was an actual Moses, for example, but not that Moses spoke to a rock and out gushed water.

The same reasoning applies to the crossing of the Red Sea.  Higher critics lean toward believing the sea was a Sea of Reeds, and that there was nothing particularly miraculous in the way the Israelites crossed that shallow body of water that could not be explained through natural phenomena.

I hope someone takes up the challenge I've issued and answers the OP's question based on knowledge which has already be acquired in this regard before I've had time to prepare a more thorough answer than my partial answer.